# How can i get the class from the all selectbox options?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the class from the current selected option and insert into a textbox, but i only can get the first class:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2qAwh/

HTML

```
<select class="josearchselect" id="templates" name="text">
<option class="1">1</option>
<option class="2">2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="log_temp_id" />
```

JQquery

```
var Element= $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class');
    $("#templates").live("change", function() {
    $(".log_temp_id").val(Element);
    });
```

And i heard that live is not being used anymore in the new JQuery versions, i dont know if its true, but i would like to replace this event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the class inside the change handler

```
$("#templates").live("change", function () {
    //you need to read the class attribute inside the change handler so that you will get the currently selected option
    var className = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class');
    $(".log_temp_id").val(className);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mknAa/)

The [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method is [no longer supported](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed), if you wish to use event delegation support for the change event handler use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for jQuery >= 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.on()` as an alternate to `.live()` in jquery versions >= 1.7,

```
$(document).on("change","#templates", function () {
    $(".log_temp_id").val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('class'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qAwh/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select class inside change event of dropdwon like this :

```
$("#templates").live("change", function() {
var Element= $(this).find('option:selected').attr('class');
        $(".log_temp_id").val(Element);
    });
```

And `.live` is deprecated after jQuery version `1.7` and removed from version `1.9`. More information click [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZcCq/9/)**

Comment: @RahulGupta, sorry, by mistake i have given some other jsfiddle. Updated now. Thanks :)